# Mod rewrite keeps appending GET string when no backslash at the end is present

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1
```

With that rewrite rules, if I enter any link that doesn't end in a backslash, `GET` string is appended at the end.

Examples:

> localhost/forum/ shows as localhost/forum/
>
> localhost/forum shows as localhost/forum/?route=Forum

Comment: where is index.php in you example gone? And how did that "f" in "forum" get to "F"?

Comment: I don't know much about mod_rewrite so I don't know how to answer that. The example is literal ilustration of what happens when I enter the address, Also the address isnt modified anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

so it won't do anything when an exsisting directory is pointed at

Comment: There is one problem, I'm making simple MVC project and each of this directories exists and cointans files used by module.

Comment: personally I place MVC directory even outside the document root. As those files should never get accessed directly. Apart from that, I think the document root get quite chaotic when every module places a directory. Why not `/mvc/forum` to at least limit the chaos.

Comment: Okay, lets move all modules elsewhere and see how it works out.

Comment: I moved everything, nothing changed. Then I emptied .htaccess to see what happens, and links were still rewritten as I never touched .htaccess. I opened my site in Chrome (was using Firefox), and guess what? Everything works as intented (first returned the error, when I filled .htaccess with rules, it started working as it should). It seems Firefox had something to do with faulty reroutes.

Comment: I suppose it is caching. Would you not want a [L] after the rewrite line?

Comment: Yeah, it was, I cleared and now it works fine on Firefox. I'm going to ditch passing route by `GET`, and use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead. Thanks for help and tips!